# Unexpected end of json input. File not able to parse completely

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen related questions on stack overflow as well as other websites and no solution worked out for me. I am working on a something which makes a get request. I am using expressjs and for get request i am using https module. The api from where I am making a get request is https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest . I confirmed that it returns a json object. The code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  const URL = 'https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest';
  https.get(URL, function(response){
    response.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });

  });
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server started");
});
```

the output i am getting is:

```sh
server started 
undefined:1 
{"success":true,"data":{"summary":{"total":343091,"confirmedCasesIndian":335359,"confirmedCasesForeign":48,"discharged":180013,"deaths":9900,"confirmedButLocationUnidentified":7684},"unofficial-summary":[{"source":"covid19india.org","total":344015,"recovered":180331,"deaths":9920,"active":153721}],"regional":[{"confirmedCasesIndian":41,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":33,"deaths":0,"loc":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands","totalConfirmed":41},{"confirmedCasesIndian":6456,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":3316,"deaths":88,"loc":"Andhra Pradesh","totalConfirmed":6456},{"confirmedCasesIndian":91,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":7,"deaths":0,"loc":"Arunac        

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sasmit\Desktop\covid 19\testapp.js:15:24)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:506:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:1006:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:987:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

seems like it is not able to parse the entire file.

Comment: it seems like the file is not to 100% valid json

Comment: i used https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json file

Answer (score 0):

It's because the response is sent in chunks. After each chunk the `data` event is emitted. But it doesn't mean the response is fully sent. To make sure the reponse is complete, you need to use `end` event and parse the reponse then:

```
const URL = 'https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest';
let result = '';
https.get(URL, function(response){
  response.on('data', function(data){
    result += data;
  });
  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to `parse` it as `JSON` it is converted to a string, which is empty, So, you can give this a try

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   var URL = 'https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest';

   https.get(URL, function(res){
       var json = '';

       res.on('data', function(data){
           json += data;
       });

       res.on('end', function(){
           var response = JSON.parse(json);
           console.log(" JSON Parserd ", response.success);
       });
   }).on('error', function(e){
         console.log("Error occured while parsing ", e);
   });
});
```